# Find number string in string and Count

Tags: java, mysql, sql, count

I have a table like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/07888/1). In a String like this `01-10-33` I'd like to know how many times which number appears in my table. For example number 01 I wanna check if it is in first row, count and check line two,three...EOF and get the count number. In the example link I tried to check if the number was in the string without success. I know I could probably get all my numbers and do this in java, but is it possible to get this with sql?

The expected results in the example would be

```
numbers-count
01 - 1
02 - 2
03 - 2
05 - 1
10 - 2
12 - 1
```

Comment: Please add the expected results (based on your SQLFiddle) to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are always in that format you could use [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to get all the parts out and count them:

```
select number, count(*)
from (
  select substring(n, 1, 2) as number
  from l  
  union all  
  select substring(n, 4, 2)
  from l  
  union all  
  select substring(n, 7, 2)
  from l
  ) a
group by number;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/07888/17)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many times "`01`" appears in the string "`01-10-33`", you can use:

```
select l.*,
       (length(n) - length(replace(n, @n, '')))/length(@n)
from l cross join
     (select @n := '01') const;
```

Note that this does not handle delimiters.  So, `'01'` will match `'001'`.  If that requirement is important:

```
select l.*,
       (length(n)+2 - length(replace(concat('-', n, '-'), @n, '')))/length(@n)
from l cross join
     (select @n := '-01-') const;
```